# How to fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

```
def timer(time):
    mins = 
    while time >= 60:
        mins += 1
        time -= 60
    print (mins + ':' + time)
timer(45)
```

I know if i do print(mins, ":" , time) that I won't get the error but I'm trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `str` from the `int`. Change your print statement to this:

```
print( str(mins) + ':' + str(time))
```

Or use string formatting:

```
print( '%d:%d' % (min, time) )
```

Or if you're using Python 3.7 or higher, you can use the f-string syntax.

```
print( f'{min}:{time}' )
```

Comment: Thank You So Much!